# rewriting links in scraped content using mod_rewrite

Tags: php, apache, mod-rewrite

I'm looking to create an iframe on my site that contains amazon.com, and I'd like to control it (see what product the user is at).
I realize I can't do this because of browser security policy issues, and the only real workaround is to feed the entire page through my server.
So I load the page and I change all the `href` values from something like

`grocery-breakfast-foods-snacks-organic/b/ref=sa_menu_gro7?ie=UTF8&node=16310101&pf_rd_p=328655101&pf_rd_s=left-nav-1&pf_rd_t=101&pf_rd_i=507846&pf_rd_m=ATVPDKIKX0DER&pf_rd_r=1S4N4RYF949Z2NS263QP`

(the links on the site are relative) to `'me.com/work.php?link='.urlencode(theirlink)`.
The problem is the amount of time this takes - plus PHP runs frequently out of memory doing this.

Could I use mod_rewrite to rewrite all domains from:

```
http://www.me.com/grocery-breakfast-foods-snacks-organic/b/ref=sa_menu_gro7?ie=UTF8&node=16310101&pf_rd_p=328655101&pf_rd_s=left-nav-1&pf_rd_t=101&pf_rd_i=507846&pf_rd_m=ATVPDKIKX0DER&pf_rd_r=1S4N4RYF949Z2NS263QP
```

to:

```
http://www.me.com/work.php?url=urlencode(thatlink)
```

And if not, are there any better options rather then going through every `<a>` tag?

Thanks!

Comment: you could use Javascript (AJAX) to track link clicks.

Answer (score 0):

Have you checked out the associates API?  You can get your data that way.

- https://affiliate-program.amazon.com/gp/advertising/api/detail/main.html
- http://developer.amazonwebservices.com/connect/entry.jspa?externalID=498&categoryID=14
- http://astore.amazon.com/